# R: Quickly read in text files with TryCatch() - comparing the processing speed of sapply and a for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, error-handling, sapply

I am attempting to read in the first line of approximately 13,000 text files and save them in a vector named `flines26`. One problem I'm encountering is that a handful of files (maybe 100 in total) are completely blank and will therefore cause `fread()` to throw an error . I've attempted to read in this data using both sapply and a for loop (with the understanding that `sapply()` should be faster).

However using the code I've written the for loop actually performs better. My attempt to use sapply seems to run slowly and results in a vector that has two fewer values than it should.

Can anyone tell if there is a problem with my attempt to use `sapply()` and `tryCatch()` - or is it more likely that this problem is specific to some anomaly in my text files?

Additionally, if anyone has some alternative ways to quickly read in the first line from a large number of text files those suggestions would be much appreciated.

## Using sapply()

```
firstline<-function(x){
    tryCatch({
     y<-fread(x,nrow=1, fill=T, header = F, sep = "")
    },
    error=function(e){
      i<-match(x,files26)
      cat("On iteration ",i,"ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")
     y<<-"<ERROR>" 
    })
    return(y)
  }

  flines26<-unlist(sapply(files26,firstline))
```

## Using a For Loop

```
  flines26<-c()
  errors<-c()

  for (i in 1:length(files26)){
    tryCatch({
       flines26[i]<-fread(files26[i],fill=T,nrow=1, header = F, sep = "")
    },
    error=function(e){
      cat("On iteration ",i,"ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")
      errors<<-c(errors,i)
      flines26[i]<<-"<ERROR>"
    })
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think `sapply` would be faster than a `for` loop?  They're both pretty much the same internally, except that `sapply` needs to make a call each time, while `for` just evaluates some code.

Comment: People usually think `sapply()` is faster than for loops because they are growing objects in the for loop, which is super slow. 
The way the OP does it is now faster (R >= 3.4), but would be very slow with older versions of R.
See https://privefl.github.io/R-presentation/beyond-stats.html#34.
It is always better to preallocate the result if you know the size of it.